# Parameter name: slidingExpiration Error after upgrade to DNN 9.2

Tags: dotnetnuke

Just upgraded my test/dev site form 8.0.4 to 9.2.0. Initial installation/upgrade looked good. No errors reported. Even initial page load was fine. Once I selected to login and provided username and password for host/user get error ASP error page. Looking at the logs getting the below error.

*Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.*

*Parameter name: slidingExpiration*

```
 CacheItemExpiredCallback cacheItemExpired)
   at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.GetCachedData[TObject](CacheItemArgs cacheItemArgs, CacheItemExpiredCallback cacheItemExpired, Boolean storeInDictionary)
   at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.CBO.DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.ICBO.GetCachedObject[TObject](CacheItemArgs cacheItemArgs, CacheItemExpiredCallback cacheItemExpired, Boolean saveInDictionary)
   at DotNetNuke.Security.Cookies.AuthCookieController.Find(String cookieValue)
   at DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to read this post by Chris Hammond:

https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155552/dnn-92-login-problems-parameter-name-slidingexpiration-error

If you need further information, I'd suggest reading through the forum thread which sparked this post:
https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/200/threadid/541946/scope/posts

Thanks

Comment: If you've gone through that already, and it didn't fix it. You likely missed something...